# Jira Application Access

Tags: bash, groovy, jira

I am working on Jira Application Access page. There are added many groups. I have a bash script which search for the new groups in LDAP and send me an email with the new ones.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script filters out the missing ACL_JIRA_*-Groups in Application   Acces List of Jira
# and informs the administrators per E-mail
count=0
write="false"
tosend="Applocation access Jira / Portfolio Permissions\nFollow entries    schould be added to Jira database:\n"
acl=$(univention-ldapsearch cn=ACL_JIRA_* | grep cn: | awk '{print $2}')
for i in $acl
do
    for j in $(cat acl_jira)
    do
        if [ "$i" != "$j" ]
        then
            write="true"
        else
            write="false"
            break
        fi
    done
    if [ "$write" == "true" ]
    then
        echo "$i" >> acl_jira
        let count=count+1
        tosend=$tosend"\n"$i
    fi
done
tosend=$tosend"\nHow to:\nAdd the entires here:\n https://jira.mobility-media.de/secure/admin/ApplicationAccess.jspa\nMore info:\n https://confluence.mobility-media.de/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=90406915  (new_acl_jira.sh)"
if [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
    /root/scripts/sendmail_script/sendmail.sh "mail" "$tosend"
    /root/scripts/sendmail_script/sendmail.sh "mail" "$tosend"
fi
```

How can I automatically add new groups to the page? Page is in jspa format.

Answer (score 0):

Jira has built in LDAP configuration. If you match the group names between LDAP and Jira for Jira-Software-administrators and Jira-Software-users for example, your users will be able to login with the respective permissions. You don’t need anything new. Then you can force all users and groups other than the built in admin users to go through LDAP, not allowing local user or group changes directly from the application.